# Webserver authentication

Tags: 7

I was looking a module that implements single sign on for MS Windows networks. I found Webserver Authentication (https://www.drupal.org/project/webserver_auth). But I activated the module before configure it and now I can't access as ADMIN, or as any other developer user to keep working on the configuration of my project.

Does anyone had this problem before and can guide me to deactivate or uninstall that module??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drush may be the best option. You have a command to uninstall a module :
drush pm-uninstall module-name

Otherwise there is a really tricky and dangerous way to do it :
Go on your database on the "system" table. And search for the line with your module and set the status to 0. After that you may need to clear your cache with the function : drupal_flush_all_caches() (add it to a index.php and remove it after).

The second method is tricky and you should prefer the one with drush. I just explain it if you don't manage to install drush on windows.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I am not too familiar with Drupal, I am first time user and learning on the go. Do you have more information about Drush?? Some tutorial?? I really want to learn the best practices for Drupal. 
I took the risky and tricky path, and it worked!

Comment: Drush is a command line tool for drupal. It will save you a lot of time and save your life (sometime). Here a basic tutorial : https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drush/
You will love it :)

Comment: Clement - Thanks I was able to resolve it using drush, the second option didn't work for me but a couple of drush commands helped..good tutorial to start with